# Am I using PySimpleGUI library wrong? What am I missing?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I'm trying to learn Python online from videos across the web. As a beginner project I chose to develope a simple system called POS (Point of Sale) with PySimpleGUI library.

There's a bug that I've been trying to fix for couple days. When I click cancel it moves back to the main window (worker window) but after selecting another worker it skips second window and moves to the third window (state window). If I repeat the same thing again, this time it moves to the fourth window.

Could you please explain me what am I doing wrong? Thank you.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg


window_list = ["worker", "item", "state", "action"]
worker_list = ["worker_1", "worker_2", "worker_3"]
item_list   = ["item_1", "item_2", "item_3", "item_4", "item_5", "item_6", "item_7"]
state_list  = ["new", "kinda new", "old"]
action_list = ["buying", "selling"]

width, height = sg.Window.get_screen_size()
sg.theme("DarkAmber")


#   window 1 - worker menu
workerButton = [ [ sg.Button("worker_1", size=(10, 5)), sg.Button("worker_2", size=(10, 5)), sg.Button("worker_3", size=(10, 5)) ],
                 [ sg.Button("EXIT", size=(10, 5)) ] ]
worker = sg.Window("CHOOSE A SELLER", workerButton, no_titlebar=False, size=(500, 500), keep_on_top=False)

#   window 2 - item menu
itemButton = [ [ sg.Button("item_1"), sg.Button("item_2") ],
               [ sg.Button("item_3"), sg.Button("item_4"), sg.Button("item_5"), sg.Button("item_6"), sg.Button("item_7") ],
               [ sg.Button("CANCEL", size=(10, 5)) ] ]
item = sg.Window("CHOOSE AN ITEM", itemButton, size=(500, 500))

#   window 3 - state menu
stateButton = [ [ sg.Button("new"), sg.Button("kinda new"), sg.Button("old") ],
                [ sg.Button("CANCEL", size=(10, 5)) ] ]
state = sg.Window("CHOOSE A STATE", stateButton, size=(500, 500))

#   window 4 - action menu
actionButton = [ [ sg.Button("buying"), sg.Button("selling") ],
                 [ sg.Button("CANCEL", size=(10, 5)) ] ]
action = sg.Window("CHOOSE AN ACTION", actionButton, size=(500, 500))


def ChoosingWorker():
    event, values = worker.read()
    if event in worker_list:
        return event
    else: # exit button
        return "EXIT"

def ChoosingItem():
    event, values = item.read()
    if event == "item_1" or event == "item_2":
        item.close()
        return event # i was thinking another feature to item_1 and item_2 thats why i separatedly check it but i haven't coded yet
    elif event in item_list:
        item.close()
        return event
    else: # cancel button
        item.close()
        return event

def ChoosingState():
    event, values = state.read()
    if event in state_list:
        state.close()
        return event
    else: # cancel button
        state.close()
        return event

def ChoosingAction():
    event, values = action.read()
    if event in action_list:
        action.close()
        return event
    else: # cancel button
        action.close()
        return event


while True:
    if ChoosingWorker() == "EXIT":
        worker.close()
        break

    switch = 1

    if switch == 1:
        if ChoosingItem() == "CANCEL":
            switch = 0

    if switch == 1:
        if ChoosingState() == "CANCEL":
            switch = 0

    if switch == 1:
        if ChoosingAction() == "CANCEL":
            switch = 0
```

Comment: [Demo_Design_Pattern_Multiple_Windows1.py](https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/blob/master/DemoPrograms/Demo_Design_Pattern_Multiple_Windows1.py) Here is a description of the window transition. I hope you find it helpful. Instead of dealing with multiple windows from the beginning, why not just create a simple single screen? This demo sample is very informative.

Comment: I think my problem is with the while loop. I build the logic wrong but i can't figure it how. The code works as you said. Opens with 1 screen and moves on to others. It is a very useful link, thank you.